# How do I use radio buttons inside popup menus?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a popup menu that contains selectable radio buttons in order to change a view type (e.g. gallery, cards, swipe, grid, list, etc.).

The issue I'm running into is that PopupMenu has its own callbacks for selecting values, and so does Radio and RadioListTile.

### Ignore RadioListTile's onChanged

Here's my first attempt. This actually works, except that the buttons are perpetually grayed out. Giving the RadioListTiles a non-null noop function results in the buttons no longer grayed out (disabled), but then the popup menu no longer works.

```
new PopupMenuButton<String>(
    ...
    itemBuilder: (ctx) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
          new PopupMenuItem(
              child: new RadioListTile(
                  title: new Text("Cards"),
                  value: 'cards',
                  groupValue: _view,
                  onChanged: null),
              value: 'cards'),
          new PopupMenuItem(
              child: new RadioListTile(
                  title: new Text("Swipe"),
                  value: 'swipe',
                  groupValue: _view,
                  onChanged: null),
              value: 'swipe'),
        ],
    onSelected: (String viewType) {
      _view = viewType;
    }));
```

### Use RadioListTile, ignore PopupMenu

Second attempt is to ignore the PopupMenu entirely and just use RadioListTile `onChanged`. The buttons are not grayed-out/disabled, but are also not functional.

```
new PopupMenuButton<String>(
  ...
  itemBuilder: (ctx) => <PopupMenuEntry<Null>>[
        new PopupMenuItem(
            child: new RadioListTile(
                title: new Text("Cards"),
                value: 'cards',
                groupValue: _view,
                onChanged: (v) => setState(() => _view = v)),
            value: 'cards'),
        new PopupMenuItem(
            child: new RadioListTile(
                title: new Text("Swipe"),
                value: 'swipe',
                groupValue: _view,
                onChanged: (v) => setState(() => _view = v)),
            value: 'swipe'),
      ],
));
```

What's the correct approach? PopupMenu works well with extremely simple menus, but the element selection is giving me conflicts. Is there a way to get a "dumb" popup menu that displays a column of widgets (styled like a menu) at the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [`PopupMenuButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) is maintaining the popup dialog as private state (it even pushes a new route onto the `Navigator` stack). Calling `setState` won't rebuild the items. You can use an [`AnimatedBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) and a [`ValueNotifier`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) to get around this.

Here's an example of a working radio button list inside a popup:

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

enum Fruit {
  apple,
  banana,
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<Fruit> _selectedItem = new ValueNotifier<Fruit>(Fruit.apple);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new PopupMenuButton<Fruit>(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new List<PopupMenuEntry<Fruit>>.generate(
              Fruit.values.length,
              (int index) {
                return new PopupMenuItem(
                  value: Fruit.values[index],
                  child: new AnimatedBuilder(
                    child: new Text(Fruit.values[index].toString()),
                    animation: _selectedItem,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                      return new RadioListTile<Fruit>(
                        value: Fruit.values[index],
                        groupValue: _selectedItem.value,
                        title: child,
                        onChanged: (Fruit value) {
                          _selectedItem.value = value;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just had a look at the CheckedPopupMenuItem class. It seems it should not be to much work to introduce the possibility to choose the icon which is used as leading widget, would it? Do you think this would be a wasted effort to make a pull request for this?

Comment: It's not really going to solve your issue unless you have a way for one item to force the others to rebuild.

Comment: Can the popup menu width be adjustable? I wanted to made it smaller and wanted to remove all white spaces and make it really fit one. Help

Answer (score 6):

I think the best solution for you would be to use [CheckedPopupMenuItems](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CheckedPopupMenuItem-class.html) instead of a radio list. The functionality should be exactly what you want to achieve, isn't it?

Here is a small example:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _selectedView = 'Card';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('TestProject'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (value) => setState(() => _selectedView = value),
            itemBuilder: (_) => [
                  new CheckedPopupMenuItem(
                    checked: _selectedView == 'Card',
                    value: 'Card',
                    child: new Text('Card'),
                  ),
                  new CheckedPopupMenuItem(
                    checked: _selectedView == 'Swipe',
                    value: 'Swipe',
                    child: new Text('Swipe'),
                  ),
                  new CheckedPopupMenuItem(
                    checked: _selectedView == 'List',
                    value: 'List',
                    child: new Text('List'),
                  ),
                ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new Center(child: new Text(_selectedView)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's close and works well enough, but I'd still like to have the radio buttons since those are more familiar. I'll probably just take a look at the source for CheckedPopupMenuItem and go from there.

Comment: This answer may not be something what @perlatus was looking for. however it works perfectly for me as i was looking at a way to set and unset a checkbox in popupmenu