# how to create radio button inside the dropdown menu in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[This type of dropdown.. I have tried more times in using a ListTile widget.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l7Ht.jpg)

Comment: This may help you.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085543/how-do-i-use-radio-buttons-inside-popup-menus

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a RadioListTile for this purpose. this code is from the flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html), you can try it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter { lafayette, jefferson }

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.lafayette;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Lafayette'),
          value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Thomas Jefferson'),
          value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you got your answer accept the answer to close this question topic.

Comment: No, because I need inside a RadioListTile in DropDownButton. It is possible?

Comment: you can mix it with dropdownbutton in return dropdownmenu.

Comment: Hai dude, I have another doubt!